# how to fix "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll"

Tags: c#, vb.net

when I run the code it runs. the login and register form appears. But after entering details when clicking on the register button it shows the error

"An unhandled exception of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception' occurred in system.data.dll"
and highlight the **con** and **con.open()**

the coding is given below

namespace MovieBookingSystemCSharp
{
    public partial class Register : Form
    {
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection **con** = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\dell\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MovieBookingSystemCSharp\MovieBookingSystemCSharp\movie.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        **con.Open();**

        try
        {
            string str = "INSERT INTO user1(name,mobile,email,pass) VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "'); ";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //-------------------------------------------//

            string str1 = "select max(Id) from user1;";

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New User Registered Successfully..");
                Form1 obj = new Form1();
                obj.ShowDialog();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox3.Text = "";
        TextBox4.Text = "";

    }
}
```

}

Comment: SQL Exceptions *do* have much more details. Please examine (and post) inner exception too. By the way, don't construct statements like this, use statement parameters instead.

Comment: where do I find inner exceptions?

Comment: That has never been the correct way to compose SQL in NET.  You may want to consult the documentation or any of tens of thousands of posts here.  How does a `SELECT MAX()` query tell you that the user was registered?

Comment: Visual Studio will pop up a dialog, like this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/03/help3_thumb.png . At the bottom, you will see View Details.

Comment: i cant add exeptions here they are too long

Comment: Start with the exception message. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the "AttachDbFilename" property without spaces in the path like shown below.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\testuser1\Documents\vs2015\Projects\MovieBookingSystemCSharp\MovieBookingSystemCSharp\movie.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: Changing the path to the database file will help? Really?